# System menu and desktop right click don't appear in Gnome3

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome3, desktop-environment, gnome-panel

I run Arch Linux with Gnome3. I need to escape from the "routine" and change to Gnome for some weeks or even months. When I open it, I can't see the system menu, which is supposed to be right of "places", and cannot right click my desktop.

Is my Gnome corrupted?

Comment: try pacman -Syu and check whether it get resolved or try gnome-tweak-tool -> file manager -> have the file manager handle the desktop

Comment: Ok, found tweak tool...what about system menu? :S

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the GNOME Tweak Tool will allow you to let the file manager manage the desktop which will bring back icons and context menu to your desktop. As for a system applications menu, if you don't like using the Overview, you could install GNOME Shell Extensions to add functionality. Check out [3 Taskbar Options for GNOME 3.2](http://www.micahcarrick.com/3-taskbars-for-gnome-3.html). The first taskbar option shown includes `mgse-menu` which is a pretty cool system menu.

There are a couple of other menu extensions available at [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/) including an Applications menu and a Places menu.